# Is it right to resend HTTP request on TCP RST packet, which has already been sent?

Tags: http, connection, packet

**The environment:**
An intranet: two same Web servers, two application servers, a layer 4 switch(load balancer) and an SSL accelerator are working and all the clients(my users) are using Windows 7 and Internet explorer.

**What I faced:**
The service my application offers takes usually 3-7 minutes to process an HTTP request users make, on average and when the processing time exceeds 5 minutes, an HTTP request which is the exactly same with the first request(header, body) is automatically sent by the client.

**What I figure out:**
I captured packets using Wireshark and figured out what had happened; the server-side(I haven't exactly figured out which layer is the exact suspect yet) sends an RST packet when a request is being processed over 5 minutes and the client get RST packet and resend the same request.

So it makes two same duplicated requests on one request which exceeds 5 minutes to be processed.

**What I wonder:**
Is it a proper behavior to resend HTTP request on TCP RST packet, which has already been sent? Can I configure the behavior??

Answer (score 0):

Opinions vary here. For an *idempotent* request (e.g. a HTTP "GET") it's generally fine to do this, especially if you haven't gotten any valid response from the server so far. For a *non-idempotent* request (e.g. a HTTP "PUT") you're meant to ask the user for permission.

If you happen to know that, in your scenario, repeating a request will do no harm, then it's probably fine to just repeat the request.

You *should* limit the number of times you retry, lest you end up causing a denial-of-service on yourself.